# memu emulator error "The core process of emulator has ended "

Tags: android, emulation

Every time i open memu it gives me this error and gets stuck. if i click OK the emulator gets closed
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBB3L.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Launch Multi-Memu (The multiinstance manager), reduce the RAM and CPU count, you can also change the Render Mode, then launch from the manager.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed render mode from OpenGL to DirectX and it's working fine now

Comment: give more explanation about the reason. it will help more to the community